# How to use two rows, one with a slideshow and the next one with an image, as background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, to create a web application.

For the home page, I want to recreate the effect similar to the below template:

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/52270.html

I made many attempts to achieve a fixed header in the first row, with the second row having a slideshow for background and the third row has a simple complementing image for background. The second and third row together provide a backdrop for the animated tabs to slide in at a precise position.

So far I have achieved a slideshow that stretches into the entire page, a fixed header.

Problem 1: Unable to place the tabs at the bottom of the row. As shown in the image, current position is displayed in colors and the black squares are where i want the tabs.

[image]

The code that caused this:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .trow {
        align-content: stretch;
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: auto;
        top: 0px;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    body {
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-self: center;
        background-image: url('Images_bg/Sea_02_highres.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        transition: opacity 0.3s linear, transform 0.9s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.9s ease-in-out;
    }

        body::after {
            content: "";
            background: url('Images_bg/Sea_02_highres.jpg');
            opacity: 0.3;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    #wrap {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }

        #wrap img.bgfade {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('img.bgfade').hide();
            var dg_H = $(window).height();
            var dg_W = $(window).width();
            $('#wrap').css({ 'height': dg_H, 'width': dg_W });
            function anim() {
                $("#wrap img.bgfade").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(1500);
                $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(2000);
                setTimeout(anim, 4000);
            }
            anim();
        })
        $(window).resize(function () { window.location.href = window.location.href })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/nfspain_sea_p.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/8.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/Sea_02_highres.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/351539-admin.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/cargo-ship.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/cargo_ship_pollution_wallpaper-other.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/cargo_ship_wallpaper_3-wide.jpg" />
        <img class="bgfade" src="Images_bg/maersk_line_cargo_ship_1920x1200_22372.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Table ID="table1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow Width="100%" BackColor="White">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell ColumnSpan="2" BackColor="White" Width="90%" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle">
                    <asp:Image ID="img_banner" runat="server" Width="90%" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/Images/logistics-and-stores-banner.png" />
                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableRow Width="100%" VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                <asp:TableCell Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_logistics" runat="server" BackColor="#E74C3C" Width="200px" Height="150px" Text="Logistics" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="White" OnClick="lb_logistics_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Bottom">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_stores" runat="server" BackColor="#9DC02E" Text="Stores" Width="200px" Height="150px" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="White"></asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Problem 2:** On clicking Logistics I get redirected to a page with fixed header, it has caused the accordion in the next row to be shadowed. The image says it better:

[image]

The code that gave this effect is:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-self: center;
        background-image: url('Images_bg/Sea_02_highres.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 90%;
        width: 90%;
        transition: opacity 0.3s linear, transform 0.9s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.9s ease-in-out;
    }

        body::after {
            content: "";
            background: url('Images_bg/Sea_02_highres.jpg');
            opacity: 0.3;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
        }

    div.transbox {
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-self: center;
        margin: 22px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        opacity: 0.9;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    div.tansparentbox {
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-self: center;
        margin: 22px;
        background-color: gray;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        opacity: 0.6;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: thin;
        border-color: black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    .trow {
        position: fixed;
        align-content: stretch;
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: auto;
        top: 0px;
        font-size: larger;
    }

    .trow2:hover {
        font-size: xx-large;
        background-color: azure;
        text-decoration: chocolate underline solid;
        text-decoration-style: solid;
        animation: ease-in 4s ease 4 infinite;
    }

    .cellstyle {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .tblbg {
        background-color: #d7d7d7;
    }
    /*Accordion menu(side) design css*/
    .accordionHeader {
        border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;
        color: white;
        background-color: #2E4d7B;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1;
    }

        .accordionHeader:hover {
            background-color: #4676ba;
        }

    #master_content .accordionHeader a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        opacity: 1;
    }

        #master_content .accordionHeader a:hover {
            background: none;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bold;
            opacity: 1;
        }

    .accordionHeaderSelected {
        border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;
        color: white;
        background-color: #5078B3;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    #master_content .accordionHeaderSelected a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        opacity: 0.9;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: navy;
        opacity: 1;
    }

        #master_content .accordionHeaderSelected a:hover {
            background: none;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bold;
            opacity: 1;
            color: navy;
        }

    .accordionContent {
        background-color: #D3DEEF;
        border: 1px dashed #2F4F4F;
        border-top: none;
        padding: 5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        opacity: 1;
        color: navy;
    }

    #wrap {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }

        #wrap img.bgfade {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
</style>
```

How do I achieve the effects similar to the template?

How do i achieve fixed position for the tabs and avoid the shadowing of fixed header over the next row?